# Put username in apache access_log with PHP and without HTTP auth

Tags: php, apache, http, authentication, logging

In the Apache log configuration it is possible to specify that the HTTP auth user name should be logged. Most PHP scripts have their own, cookie-based authentication. Is it possible in PHP to provide Apache with a HTTP auth username for logging purposes, even if the authentication is cookie-based? If yes, how would the code look like? If not, what are alternatives?

Comment: I don't think it's good idea. Why not to use a separate logfile?

Comment: Because I would like to do simple statistics with a tool like AWStats.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apache passes data between modules in *notes*. If you run PHP as an Apache module, you can use [`apache_note()`](http://php.net/apache_note) to get and set notes. You can then include [the `%{note_name}n` log format string](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) to write this to the access log. This will not "leak" any data back to the client.

In PHP:

```
apache_note( 'username', $username );
```

In your server configuration:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %{username}n %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_with_php_username
CustomLog logs/access_log common_with_php_username
```

Comment: What happens if the username value is not defined by apache_note() ? Is ${username} crash log insertion or leave blank value ?

Comment: @jedema Not sure, I think either blank or a dash (`-`). I don't have a setup to test it now, but if you do, can you let us know the results?

Comment: It uses a `-` if it's not set.

Answer (score 11):

Since Apache 2.4.7 Apache allows you to copy a response-header to a note. So if you don't run PHP as an Apache module (but for instance use PHP-FPM), and you also don't want the log-value to be sent to the client (which would usually happen if you set it in a response-header), here's a way to do it:

php:

```
header('X-Username: '.$username);
```

httpd.conf:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{username}n\"" logfmtname
```

vhost.conf:

```
CustomLog logs/vhost-access_log logfmtname

# copy response-header value to note
Header note X-Username username
# unset response-header so client won't get it
Header unset X-Username
```

Answer (score 2):

A possibility is to store usernames & past session_ids somewhere else, and let the log write the cookie values in it (usually `%{PHPSESSID}C`), which you then can trace back.

Another option would be to send a header with the username back to the client, preferably right after your `session_start`:

PHP:

```
header('X-Php-Sess-User: '.$username);
```

Customlog:

```
%{X-Php-Sess-User}o
```

Answer (score 0):

Short of using an Apache handler to touch the internal auth* data structures, your best bet is to resort to environment variables. You would set a top-level environment variable using apache_setenv in your PHP code

```
apache_setenv('USERID','jrodriguez',true);
```

and then write the value to the log file with a LogFormat entry in your Apache config using "%{USERID}e" instead of "%u"

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %{USERID}e %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" envuid_combined
CustomLog /path/to/access.log envuid_combined
```

Of course, the real credentials when performing *actual* HTTP auth would be lost forever, so consider saving %u somewhere else -- either in a new field or in a parallel log file.

Comment: wouldn't a environment variable be global and as such be unreliable

Comment: @Esben Not sure exactly what you mean, but in general, no - an envorioment variable is not global. The above solution works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I second "towr" answer about

```
header('X-Username: '.$username);
```

I though would add what made my configuration work.

1. The **headers** apache module is required (if not enabled it would raise an error)
2. The apache statements needed the **always** option

```
CustomLog logs/vhost-access_log logfmtname

# copy response-header value to note
Header always note X-Username username
# unset response-header so client won't get it
Header always unset X-Username
```