# Can I log data from $_SESSION to apache's custom (access) log?

Tags: php, apache2

When I have my user's IDs in `$_SESSION['user']['id']` and I want to store this ID in apache2's custom log, is this possible?

Either with apache 2.2 or apache 2.4. Doesn't matter.

So for example, line as this:

```
61963   85.162.206.25   [14/Sep/2013:22:17:07 +0000]    9088    /index.php
```

Would become:

```
61963   85.162.206.25   [14/Sep/2013:22:17:07 +0000]    9088    /index.php  20
```

Indicating that it was user ID 20. `// as $_SESSION['user']['id'] == 20`

Comment: sure, if the user that the web server is running under has permissions to write to the apache2 log files

Comment: I was hoping for **how** is it done.

Comment: it could be done in a myriad of ways, because we are talking *nix, right? if web-server user has permission, then it would be trivial. here's a [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470716/writing-to-apache-access-log-file-with-php) about it. try it yourself (under debian6 for me), `file_put_contents('/var/log/apache2/access.log',$msg,FILE_APPEND)`. for ease of the eyes, make message format the same as what's already there

Comment: Oh, I'm not talking about writing it with php. I'm talking about the apache2's [mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html).

Comment: well i'll be no help then. however, since logging will come from php ( i assume) then log what you want. if web-server user has the permissions then i dont understand the problem, as you can do as you please with the right permissions