# PHP Traffic accounting

Tags: php, traffic-measurement

we're calculating the traffic usage of customers with access logs of NGINX / apache.
Now a big question came to my mind.

What if I do this:

```
<?php
    file_get_contents( "http://www.speedtest.qsc.de/1GB.qsc" );
?>
```

The call itself would be a simple GET with just a few bytes / kilobytes, but assuming we have enough memory_limit and max_execution_time, the script would download a 1GB file.
This wouldn't be logged at all, right?

Is there any way to track something like I mentioned above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

for apache the default log is

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"
```

the %b represents the `Size of response in bytes, excluding HTTP headers. In CLF format, i.e. a '-' rather than a 0 when no bytes are sent`

You could probably use that

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html

for nginx its also default

```
log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                       '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

Comment: that won't count the traffic a php download-call would make if the downloaded file is not shown and simply discarded. the response would be 0 bytes (no output)

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470716/writing-to-apache-access-log-file-with-php

Comment: sadly not - we can't change anything in the customers code, so we can't add any special logging commands to the source itself.