# PHP: Sending info to access.log, errors to error.log

Tags: php, apache, logging

I have a legacy app that runs under PHP and Apache.

It does all its logging via `error_log()`, which ends up in Apache's `error.log`.

I'd like to only send error messages to `error.log`, and send other logging to `access.log`.

What are my options? I would rather not drastically overhaul the Apache's logs format, because other tools parse it.

- I see [a solution using `apache_note`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12145635/223424).
- I can imagine that making both Apache and PHP write to syslog, and configuring syslog to filter the messages by source and severity would allow me to have neat `access.log` and `error.log` with two or more writers.

Am I missing a simpler solution?

Comment: `access.log` is *not* for application logging. Use a PSR-3 logger like [Monolog](https://packagist.org/packages/monolog/monolog) for application logging.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: Please make your comment a proper answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Heh ok. Didn't think it contained enough detail for a full answer, I've elaborated a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`access.log` is intended to record web server connection activity, and should not be used for application logging. See [`PSR-3`](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/) for a definition of a logger interface. This is implemented by popular packages like [Monolog](https://packagist.org/packages/monolog/monolog).