# Put username in apache access_log with Perl and without HTTP auth

Tags: apache, perl, http, authentication, logging

How do we put username is `apache access_log` with Perl without `HTTP` auth? For PHP, the solution is in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389169/put-username-in-apache-access-log-with-php-and-without-http-auth).

I need to achieve the similar result using Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar mechanism to the way PHP does this in `mod_perl`: https://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/RequestRec.html#C_notes_ .

Of course you need to run `mod_perl` in this case and not a simple CGI script. But this is also valid for the PHP solution which would work with `mod_php` but not when running using PHP as a CGI script. The reason is that CGI scripts are a separate process and don't have access to the internal state of the request inside Apache and can not manipulate it.

With a CGI script you might instead write the information into a response header and log this as described [here](http://archive.ianwinter.co.uk/2010/11/18/log-response-headers-in-apache/). But remember that this header is also sent to the browser, so don't put confidential information in it.